# Replacement of string using Regex

Tags: java, regex, sed

I am trying to replace all occurancces of `convert(string1,string2) to CAST(<String2> AS <String1>)`.

INPUT STRING is as below:

```
Insert Into `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchResult`(SearchLinkID,PWUserID,SearchRank) 
        Select distinct lnk.SearchLinkID, Convert(varchar(10),@PWUserID) ,Convert(varchar(10),@rank) from `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchLink` lnk (nolock)
        inner join `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchTag` tg (nolock) on lnk.SearchLinkID = tg.SearchLinkID         
        WHERE @strSearch
```

DESIRED OUTPUT STRING:

```
Insert Into `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchResult`(SearchLinkID,PWUserID,SearchRank) 
        Select distinct lnk.SearchLinkID, CAST(@PWUserID AS varchar(10)) ,CAST(@rank AS varchar(10)) from `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchLink` lnk (nolock)
        inner join `Collaboration`.`SR_SearchTag` tg (nolock) on lnk.SearchLinkID = tg.SearchLinkID         
        WHERE @strSearch
```

I tried a lot from my side but not able to do this. Please help me.

Comment: could a weird pattern like this `...convert( lazy(dog,is,(running), fast),or(,,not())) ...` be present (internal `()` with `,` inside ?

Comment: regex Convert(?:\(([^,]*),([^)]*)\)) https://regex101.com/r/tG4gF2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sed.

```
$ sed 's/\bConvert(\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))/CAST(\2 AS \1)/gi' file
Insert Into Collaboration.SR_SearchResult(SearchLinkID,PWUserID,SearchRank) Select distinct lnk.SearchLinkID, CAST(@PWUserID AS varchar(10)) ,CAST(@rank AS varchar(10)) from Collaboration.SR_SearchLink lnk (nolock) inner join Collaboration.SR_SearchTag tg (nolock) on lnk.SearchLinkID = tg.SearchLinkID
WHERE @strSearch
```

To save the changes made, you need to add `-i` parameter like, `sed -i 's//gi'` . `i` modifier helps to do a case in-sensitive match.

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj. With your help, I got my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java, you could use the following regular expression: `convert\((.+?),(.+?)\)` and use it like so (sample example [here](https://regex101.com/r/zK0fC0/1)):

```
String str = "Insert Into Collaboration.SR_SearchResult(SearchLinkID,PWUserID,SearchRank) Select distinct lnk.SearchLinkID, Convert(varchar(10),@PWUserID) ,Convert(varchar(10),@rank) from Collaboration.SR_SearchLink lnk (nolock) inner join Collaboration.SR_SearchTag tg (nolock) on lnk.SearchLinkID = tg.SearchLinkID\n" +
"WHERE @strSearch";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("Convert\\((.+?),(.+?)\\)", "CAST($2 AS $1)"));
```

Yields:

```
Insert Into Collaboration.SR_SearchResult(SearchLinkID,PWUserID,SearchRank) Select distinct lnk.SearchLinkID, CAST(@PWUserID AS varchar(10)) ,CAST(@rank AS varchar(10)) from Collaboration.SR_SearchLink lnk (nolock) inner join Collaboration.SR_SearchTag tg (nolock) on lnk.SearchLinkID = tg.SearchLinkID
WHERE @strSearch
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is:

```
sed 's/Convert(\(.*\),\(.*\))/CAST(\2 AS \1)/g'
```

Comment: it won't work. Avinash Raj solution is perfect in sed.